# associating and combining different models and controllers together in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I am having one of those coder's block. Right now I have two models and two controllers, **Trip** and **Travel-Time**. The pseudo-code is below

```
Trip contains
- Destination
- Link
- Duration
- Coment

Travel-Time contains
- Duration
```

I want to associate them together in meaningful ways, something close to the following.

A single Journey has multiple travel-time and multiple trips, like the pseudo-code below

```
Journey contains
- Trip #1
- Travel-Time #1
- Trip #2
- Travel-Time #2
```

I know how to create the **Trip** controller/model and the **Travel-Time** controller/model, but how should I begin with the Journey controller/model?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a journey_id attribute to Trip and Travel-Time.
Inside trip.rb and travel_time.rb insert

```
belongs_to :journey
```

and inside journey.rb, insert

```
has_many :trips
has_many :travel_times
```